# Split a string into a list and then split the result and get value

Tags: model-view-controller, split, request

I have a problem with a split function. My goal is to get a value from an JSON object where there's a key and value. I only want the value from the object. I have made a split function to split it when it hits the character (',') and then i get a key, value object like a KeyValuePair list. But how do i get the value then from the list?

I am deveoloping a logging function and this is a request from my API. Any Suggestions?

Here is my simple code:

```
request.InputStream.Position = 0;
var it = reader.ReadToEnd();
var list = it.Split(',').ToList();

foreach (var res in list)
{
   //What to do here?               
}
```

Here is one post in the list:

"{\"id\":\"45698745698521\""}

Then after the split i want to be able to match the id with object property so
this is what i want be able to do

```
consumer.id = id.Value();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the **JsonConvert**

```
var customer = new CustomerLayoutRenderer(); 
var requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();

customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerLayoutRenderer>(requestBody);
```

I used Jsonconvert to deserialize my object and then i could play around with it much easier!